# How to build Super CSV with maven

Tags: supercsv

I want to build Super CSV code cloned from the git repository: https://github.com/super-csv/super-csv

First of all Maven complains since the project is setup for java 1.5 and Maven uses 1.6. I have tried to change to 1.6 in pom-file but then I get a JavaDoc error.

Is the project abandoned? If not can you supply some info about how to build?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ex maintainer here.

> Is the project abandoned?

I think you can probably tell from Github that there hasn't been any activity for a few years. Kasper was looking for people to help maintain the project, but it looks like it's fizzled out. Back when I worked on it the README was correct (it *was* actively maintained)!

> can you supply some info about how to build?

If you wanted to compile for 1.5, you might be able to find an old Java 8 JDK (the project was built on JDK8 but the main module compiled for 1.5) but it looks current versions of JDK8 have deprecated 1.5.

Like you say, upgrading to 6 causes the javadoc to fail (as it uses deprecated syntax like `<tt>` tags). You can simply comment out the javadoc plugin configuration in `pom.xml` to work around that.

For what it's worth I got it to compile with JDK8, setting to Java 6 in the `maven-compiler-plugin` config and disabling the javadoc plugin.